# Perform a task (in iOS) after animation has finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation

So I have this line of code:

`[tableView setContentOffset:point animated:YES];`

and I want to run another piece of code after the animation ends. My attempt was to throw the animating code (setContentOffset) in a separate method and calling it using:

`[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(scrollMethod:) withObject:sender waitUntilDone:YES];`

The problem is that the method returns immediately, not after the animation is finished, even though waitUntilDone is YES, but apparently that is how animation works.

I know that I can use thread waiting but it is not clean, so I will only use it as a last resort. (Maybe I would use this if I know the time it takes the scrolling animation to happen.)

Any ideas on how to go about this are welcome.

(P.S. The scenario is this: I am showing a popover, which is displayed perfectly when there is no keyboard, however, if the keyboard is visible, the popover's height shrinks which sometimes reduces it to almost border only. So just before showing the popover, I want to scroll the view upwards so that the popover never pops in the keyboard.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // Do your animations here.
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (finished) {
                         // Do your method here after your animation.
                     }
                 }];
```

Comment: Was going to answer the same... I'm wondering if this will interfere with the tableView animations though.

Comment: Then my new answer is still useful for educational purposes :)

Comment: Thanks Kjuly for the answer. This works fine for me since I want the popoverDisplayMethod to execute only on one specific instance. This gives me the power and flexibility to do it.

Answer (score 35):

UITableView inherits setContentOffset:animated: from its superclass, UIScrollView.  Check out the scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation: method of UIScrollViewDelegate.

Comment: +1 for actually reading the question and giving the only correct answer.

Comment: Thanks rob. +1 for this simple method.

Answer (score 1):

For a scrollView, tableView or collectionView if you do something like this:

```
[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x+260.0,
                                                      self.collectionView.contentOffset.y)
                                 animated:YES];
```

then you'll get back a:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

when the scroll finishes.

You do NOT get this callback if the user moves the view.

Answer (score 0):

You can create animations and tell them directly to perform a block after they're done.

Here's an alternative that may play nicer with the UITableView's animations.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:sender];
[UIView setDelegate:self];
[UIView setDidStopSelector:@selector(scrollMethod:)];
[tableView setContentOffset:point];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And make sure to implement your `scrollMethod:` with this signature:

```
- (void)scrollMethod:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
```

You can use the context to know which `sender` you have. Read the [UIView docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) for more on UIView animations.

Comment: @Till It changed after I started answering, so no. Also, if you're going to be snarky about it, when the question asks for ideas (Did YOU read the entire question?), there is no correct answer ;)

Comment: the question has been asked 27minutes ago. You answered 10 minutes ago and the question has not been edited. Not sure what changed on your screen.

Comment: @Till Apparently if you edit your question fast enough, it doesn't show up as edited (probably to give the asker time to quickly correct small mistakes without cluttering the site). I know this, because my own question doesn't state an edit time either. Anyway, being snarky is never nice nor a good idea on these types of sites.

Comment: Hi @Till it did changed, it is strange why there's no edit version. :?

Comment: Well in that case I need to apologize and take everything back.

Comment: Hmm, it should not have changed... At least I did not change it! I posted only once :)

Comment: [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(scrollMethod:)]; instead of [UIView setDidStopSelector:@selector(scrollMethod:)];