# Perform method after adjustRegion animation finish

Tags: ios

The task I am trying to do is, user press a "share" button, set the region for mapview, take a screenshot of the mapview, then post on Facebook.

In theory it works fine, except sometime the device took the screenshot before setRegion finished loading.

I tried to use

```
[self performSelector:@selector(shareMap) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

However, This will not be an optimal solution especially on slow devices. 
Is there any solution that can perform this? I saw solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267173/perform-a-task-in-ios-after-animation-has-finished), but I don't understand how it works. (would it work in my situation?)

thank you.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:

Comment: (that should have been a direct link to mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap)

Comment: It does not work, because I don't always share my map everytime I load finish loading my map.

Comment: um, just keep a flag of whether you actually want to share it when it finishes moving. `true` = share, `false` = ignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for [regionDidChangeAnimated](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008204-CH3-SW4) delegate method.

Inside .h:

```
bool bSharedAlready;
```

Inside .m:

```
- (void)mapView: regionDidChangeAnimated:
{
    if (bSharedAlready)
       return;

    //Code to share on FB
    bSharedAlready = YES;
}
```

Comment: The method get called everytime the region was changed. But I don't won't want to call the "share on facebook" method everything the user change the region. How can I do that?

Comment: set a class level bool var first time you do it within regionDidChangeAnimated. Check it every time you share on FB.